# EditText addTextChangedListener call method on EditText Empty

Tags: android, android-edittext

This is my code for checking if an `EditText` is empty or not?

```
searchEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.v(TAG, "s-->" + s);
            Log.v(TAG, "count-->" + count);
            if (count == 0) {
                // call method
            }
}
```

When I remove space from the `EditText` count returns zero, and my method gets called, which is wrong..

I also tried this code but also same problem len is zero when I remove space

```
int len = searchEdit.getText().toString().trim().length();
Log.v(TAG, "len-->" + len);
```

I entered  *"us us"*  then remove it by pressing back press..

Log cat:

```
s-->u

count-->1

s-->us

count-->2

s-->us

count-->2

s-->us 

count-->1

s-->us u

count-->1

length=5

s-->us us

count-->2

s-->us u

count-->1

s-->us 

count-->0

s-->us

**count-->0**

**s-->**

**count-->0**

s-->us

count-->2

s-->u

count-->1

s-->

count-->0
```

Suggest me solution to call method when user clears the `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this code,I checked it on my machine and works perfect.:

```
        final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String ss = editText.getText().toString();
            Log.e("editext", "length ---" + ss.length());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: length is zero when I remove space.
sorry this is not working.

Comment: you are doing something wrong as i did that so many times there is nothing wrong happened with me so pls post some more code so we can understand

Comment: see my update answer.. it is working perfect.. pls check your code twice your just use my code...

Answer (score 0):

use `s.length()` for getting the char number.

```
if (s.length() == 0)
{
// do your job
}
```

use this, maybe can help you:

```
String sUsername = searchEdit.getText().toString();
if (sUsername.matches(""))
{
// do your job
}
```

Comment: s.length() return zero when I remove space.

Comment: how you remove space?

Comment: By pressing back press from device keyboard.

Comment: can you log s.length() in your code? and check when its equal zero and why, because i use this before and worked fine

Comment: Enter string with space like "hi hello" and then remove back press, when I remove a space s.length() gives zero..

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                // call method
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's get called when I remove space from EditText.